# Stuck on conditionally enable or disable input with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am attempting to conditionally enable or disable HTML input based on the value of a variable. The "disable" part is working well, but the "enable" isn't, and I can't figure out why.

The code:

```
<--if variable is true...-->
<div id="disabledSearch" class="searchBox disabled">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#disabledSearch :input').attr('disabled', true); 
    </script>

<--if variable is false-->
<div id="enabledSearch" class="searchBox">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //This line isn't working:  
        $('#enabledSearch :input').removeAttr('disabled');
    </script>
```

Comment: On a side note, you should use `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` to disable the input element.

Comment: I disagree that "disabled" is a more correct value than simple boolean `true`.  The attribute is explicitly defined in the DOM spec as boolean, and setting it to `true` works in every browser I know of. I believe the notion stems from the need to give the attribute a value in XHTML documents, instead of simply supplying it sans value the way one does in HTML. That, however, has nothing to do with how the attribute is manipulated from Javascript.

Comment: So you're embedding the scripts in your HTML? Fine, but then where are the `<input>` elements in relation to your scripts? The order will be import unless you run the code after the DOM is loaded. We're lacking some important info here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @pointy - I changed the order now it works

Edit: I can't seem to find the comment by @pointy that gave me this idea. However, the solution was that I changed around the order of the elements and javascript on the page.

Comment: This looks like a **comment**. Not an answer. Please use the comments functionality. You've asked more than 50 questions here. You should have a pretty good idea of how things work here. (Posting relevant code in your question being another example.)

Comment: If you intended this to make reference to your solution, please be specific. I don't see any place where @Pointy commented or answered with regard to order. As such, this *answer* isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I played around with this for a bit - check out http://jsbin.com/ayoye3

`input.attr('disabled',true)` and `input.attr('disabled',false)` successfully toggle the inputs.

The only possibility is that you're not selecting the correct elements, and so the code doesn't appear to work. Make sure your selectors are choosing the correct nodes, or share more of your code here - you might need to place your functions in a `$(function() { ... })` wrapper to ensure they only execute once the DOM is loaded.

Also, are you getting any js-related browser errors?

Answer (score 1):

instead of removeAttr 
try

```
$('#enabledSearch :input').attr('disabled', false);
```

Note: just a suggestion but you should probably do this in the $(document).ready() function. this would clean up some of the duplicate code that you have.

---

**Edited**

Look at migrating the code to $(document).ready( function() {}); and using the $.toggle() function to toggle disabled on the input depending on the condition.  Note if the condition is only referenced on the server side you can expose the flag on the client side by placing it in a hidden input.

Personally I would do something like this assuming you do have a valid input under the div

```
<div id="searchDiv" class="searchBox <%=SearchIsDisabled ? "disabled" : "enabled"%>"> 
    <input name="myinput" value="" type="text" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#searchDiv.disabled input).attr('disabled', true);
           $("#searchDiv.enabled input).attr('disabled', false);
        })
</script>
```

Comment: `removeAttr` should definitely work for this, I've used it lots of times myself.